# What are the correct stats for Remnant in Legacy: Life Among The Ruins?

Tags: powered-by-the-apocalypse, legacy-life-among-the-ruins

On p. 194 in Legacy: Life Among The Ruins 2nd Edition, the second and third stat sets of the Remnant are identical ("Force -1, Lore +1, Steel 0, Sway +1"), so one of them must obviously be wrong. Any ideas what the correct numbers in the third set of stats should be, anyone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I reached out to the author about this, and since they haven't signed up to answer here I'll share the answer they gave me.

> the correct statline is 'Force +1, Lore +1, Steel -1, Sway 0'.

Comment: I assume you reached out/they responded via email (or some other source that isn't public and thus can't be linked)?

Comment: @V2Blast Yes. I realize this gives me like no credibility on this. Official errata is a more time-consuming process and I'll keep up with the author's site and update with a publicly verifiable link when I can.